# Conditions for uniqueness of the solution of a linear system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, systems-of-equations, algebraic-graph-theory

**QUESTION**

Consider the positive integers, $N,\{T_n\}_{n=1}^N,J$, where $N>\max\{T_1,...,T_N\}$, $N>J$. $1_{a}$ denotes the $a\times 1$ vector of ones.

Consider the system of equations
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
D'Y\\
F'Y
\end{pmatrix}= \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
D'D & D'F\\
F'D & F'F
\end{pmatrix}}_{\equiv W} 
\beta
$$
where $Y$ is an $\sum_{n=1}^N T_n\times 1$ vector; $D$ is an $\sum_{n=1}^N T_n\times N$ matrix; $F$ is an $\sum_{n=1}^N T_n\times J$ matrix; $\beta$ is an $(N+J)\times 1$ vector.

Could you help me to find some necessary (and, if possible, also sufficient) conditions such that the system has a unique solution wrto $\beta$. That is, such that the matrix $W$ is invertible?

I report below some properties of the system that I analyse.

**Note**: a recent question of mine ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4009778/uniqueness-of-the-solution-of-a-linear-system-of-equations)) seems very similar. However, there is a key difference that prevents me from implementing the same answer: it is the fact that here the matrices $D$ and $F$ can be decomposed in blocks that do not have necessarily the same dimension. If you believe that the same answer can be applied, please advise on how.

---

**SOME PROPERTIES OF THE SYSTEM**

$Y$ does not have elements equal to zero. The matrices $F$ and $D$ have specific structures.

With regards to the matrix $F$:

- Let me decompose $F$ in $N$ submatrices, but cutting it every $T_1,...,T_N$ rows. Then, with some abuse of notation, let me write $F$ as the collection of such $N$ submatrices, $F\equiv \{F_1,F_2,...,F_N\}$, where each submatrix $F_i$ has size $T_i\times J$.
- **Property 1:** For each $i\in \{1,...,N\}$, the submatrix $F_i$ is such that in each row, *one and only one* element takes value in $(0,1)$ and all the other elements takes value zero.
- **Property 2:** If the submatrix $F_i$ has *each* of its nonzero elements positioned in the same columns as the submatrix $F_k$, then it should be that $F_i=F_k$.
- Construct the bipartite graph such the nodes in one side (hereafter, side 1) represent the column indices $j\in \{1,...,J\}$ and the the nodes in the other side (hereafter, side 2) represent the submatrix indices $i\in \{1,...,N\}$. Draw an edge between nodes $j\in \{1,...,J\}$ and $i\in \{1,...,N\}$ if at least one element of the $j$-th column of $F_i$ has a nonzero element.
- **Property 3:** The aforementioned bipartite graph should be such that each node in side 1 is indirectly connected to at least another node in side 1. Further, the bipartite graph should be such that each node in side 2 is indirectly connected to at least another node in side 2. **This is called a connected bipartite graph.**

For example, for $N=4$, $T_1=2$, $T_2=3$, $T_3=1$, $T_4=4$, and $J=3$, we could have
$$
F\equiv \Big\{\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
0.3 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0.1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}}_{F_1},
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
0.7 & 0 & 0\\
0.2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0.1
\end{pmatrix}}_{F_2},
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0.5\\
\end{pmatrix}}_{F_3},
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0.6\\
0 & 0 & 0.4\\
0.2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0.8 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}}_{F_4}\Big\}
$$
with bipartite graph

[image]

With regards to the matrix $D$:

- As done for $F$, let me write $D\equiv \{D_1,D_2,...,D_N\}$, where each submatrix $D_i$ has size $T_i\times N$.
- **Property 4:**  For each $i\in \{1,...,N\}$, the submatrix $D_i$ has its $i$-th column equal to $1_{T_i}$ and all the other elements equal to zero.

For example, for $N=4$, $T_1=2$, $T_2=3$, $T_3=1$, and $T_4=4$, we have
$$
D\equiv \Big\{\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0& 0\\
\end{pmatrix}}_{D_1},
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0& 0\\
0 & 1 & 0& 0\\
0 & 1 & 0& 0\\
\end{pmatrix}}_{D_2},
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1& 0\\
\end{pmatrix}}_{D_3},
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0&1\\
0 & 0 & 0&1\\
0 & 0 & 0&1\\
0 & 0 & 0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}}_{D_4}\Big\}
$$

---

Given, the properties above, $D'D$ and $F'F$ are diagonal matrices with strictly positive diagonal elements, where

$$
\underbrace{D'D}_{N\times N}=   \begin{pmatrix} 
    T_1 & & \\
    & \ddots & \\
    & & T_N
\end{pmatrix}, \underbrace{F'F}_{J\times J}=\begin{pmatrix} 
    \sum_{k=1}^{\sum_{n=1}^N T_n}F(k,1)^2 & & \\
    & \ddots & \\
    & &     \sum_{k=1}^{\sum_{n=1}^N T_n}F(k,J)^2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Further,
$$
F'D=\begin{pmatrix}
\sum_{t=1}^{T_1} F(1,t) & \sum_{t=T_1+1}^{T_1+T_2} F(1,t) & ... \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
\sum_{t=1}^{T_1} F(J,t) & \sum_{t=T_1+1}^{T_1+T_2} F(J,t) & ... \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the earlier post, $W$ is invertible if and only if $[D\ \ F]$ has a trivial nullspace.

Extend the columns of $D$ to form an orthogonal basis for $\Bbb R^k$ (where $k = \sum_n T_n$). Let $P$ denote the matrix whose columns are these additional vectors. Note that we have
$$
D'P = 0, \quad P'D = 0,
$$
and both $D'D$ and $P'P$ are diagonal. Now, note that $[D\ \ F]$ has a trivial nullspace if and only if $[D\ \ P]'[D\ \ F]$ has a trivial nullspace. Compute
$$
\pmatrix{D & P}' \pmatrix{D & F} = \pmatrix{D'D & D'F\\P'D & P'F} = \pmatrix{D'D & D'F\\0 & P'F}.
$$
We can conclude that $W$ is invertible if and only if $P'F$ has a trivial nullspace.

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask you to report what are $D,P$ in my example? Sorry, but I'm new to all these concepts.

Comment: Also, is why is that $[D F]$ has a trivial nullspace if and only if $[D P]' [D F]$ has a trivial nullspace? is this a row-operation as before?

Comment: @TEX The matrix $D$ is exactly the same as the matrix that you refer to as $D$ in your post. As for the matrix $P$, I say that you can find this by extending the columns of $D$ to an orthogonal basis. The standard way to do this is to apply the [Gram Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process).

Comment: @TEX In a sense, yes. For any matrix $M$ and an invertible matrix $A$, the matrix $AM$ has the same nullspace as $M$.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. Just to double check that I have understood. Let the columns of $D$ be denoted as $\{d_1,...,d_k\}$, each of size $k\times 1$ where $k\equiv \sum_{n=1}^N T_n$. These columns are linearly independent and hence constitutes a basis for $R^k$. Transform this basis into an an orthonormal basis, using the Gram–Schmidt process. Call the basis $\{p_1,..., p_k\}$. Let $P$ the $k\times k$ matrix with columns $\{p_1,..., p_k\}$.

Comment: @TEX Not quite: the columns $\{d_1,\dots,d_N\}$ are independent (and orthogonal!) but do not span $\Bbb R^k$ if $N < k$. First, extend this to a list of vectors that spans $\Bbb R^k$. In particular, you could consider $\{d_1,\dots,d_N,e_1,\dots,e_k\}$, where $e_1,\dots,e_k$ is the standard basis (i.e. the columns of the identity matrix). Applying the GS process to this sequence of vectors will give you suitable columns for the matrix $P$.

Comment: Thanks. In that case, $P$ would be a $k\times (N+k)$ matrix?

Comment: No, $P$ should have size $k \times (k - N)$

Comment: Sorry, but I think I have not fully understood your answer. Suppose $$D\equiv \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\
   1 & 0 & 0\\
   0 &1& 0\\
   0 &0 & 1\\
   0 &0 & 1\\
   0 & 0& 1\end{pmatrix}$$
Then, we could set 
$$ P\equiv \begin{pmatrix}1 &  0 &  0\\
  -1  &0&  0\\
   0  &0&  0\\
   0  &1&  1\\
   0 &-1&  0\\
   0  &0& -1\end{pmatrix}$$. Why I don't get that $P'P$ is diagonal?

Comment: The columns of $P$ are not orthogonal

Comment: Still, $P'D$ is zero. Why is orthogonality important in your derivations?

Comment: @TEX $P'P$ will only be diagonal if the columns of $P$ are orthogonal. I agree, however, that the result still holds: the matrix is invertible iff $P'F$ is invertible.